# How to subtract two dates in dataweave

Tags: mule, dataweave

I want to subtract my DOB from current date and compare the result into the integer in Dataweave. May I know how can I achieve this?

For example, I want something like
currentDate - DOB <= 35.

I only know one way of adding or subtracting years from the current date and that is...

currentDate - |P35Y| (will help me to subtract 35 years from 2016.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The following DataWeave code will substract the year:

```
{
    age: now.year - dateOfBirth.year
}
```

Notes: change the *dateOfBirth* with the required date.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
1) Input Data JSON: { "DOB": "2010-08-15"}, Output: { "ageCategory": "teen"}
2) When Input is { "DOB": "1980-08-15"}, Output is { "ageCategory": "adult"}
```

This can be achieved by below code in dataweave:

```
{ (ageCategory: "teen")  when ((now.year - (payload.DOB as :date).year) < 18),
(ageCategory: "adult") when ((now.year - (payload.DOB as :date).year) >= 18) }
```

Answer (score 0):

While this is old, it is a common question.  NOTE, you can subtract any two DateTime values and receive back a Period type.

For example, suppose you have an object with two arbitrary dates, start < end, e.g.:

```
{
"start": "2021-10-13 08:00:00",
"end":   "2021-10-13 16:00:00"
}
```

You can get the difference by turning those strings into DateTimes, and then subtracting start from end, like this:

```
{ timeDiff: ((payload.end replace ' ' with 'T') as DateTime)
            - ((payload.start replace ' ' with 'T') as DateTime)
}
```

In this case, timeDiff has the value:

```
|PT8H|
```

Now, you can calculate the number of seconds or minutes or whatever from this Period string.